# Set connection string in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have some integration tests that I'd like to run against LocalDB.

My config.json file has the following section...

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ""
  }
}
```

Is it possible to set this value in the build config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways. Like Powershell scripts to replace the values and ofcourse [this replace token extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

[image]
You should define your variable like below

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "#{connectstring}#"
  }
}
```

During the deployment it will get replaced with your actual values.

[Refer this SO for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790990/how-to-replace-variables-of-json-file-in-team-services)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the Configuration of Connection Strings in the target App Service for my Azure Web App.
Within the App startup I use this code to access it, and if running local for debugging it uses the config.json or secrets.json.

`Configuration.GetConnectionString("My_ConnectionString_Name");`

So you can have your local db mentioned in the secrets.json and set the productive database in the Azure App connection string (if applicable).