# Azure DevOps Pipeline Json Variable Substitution - Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, variable-substitution

How can I change the value of Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime using a Json Variable Substitution task in Azure DevOps?

This article...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic

...states:

```
If a variable name includes periods ("."), the transformation will attempt to locate the item within the hierarchy. For example, if the variable name is first.second.third, the transformation process will search for:

"first" : {
  "second": {
    "third" : "value"
  }
}

as well as "first.second.third" : "value".
```

Neither of these would be able to target a nested value with periods (.) in the name? Right?

Comment: Did you try with variable `Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime`?

Comment: Yeah I did. No joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither of these would be able to target a nested value with periods
> (.) in the name? Right?

Sorry but I'm afraid you can't be able to do that with `JSON variable substitution` for now. The official document has stated that the `JSON variable substitution` option doesn't support variables whose names contain periods. It's **not supported** by design, and it's already documented in the [Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-notes).

**As alternative workarounds:**

1. You can define the variable name in another format, something like `Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft_Hosting_Lifetime`.
2. Try using [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to change the value of `Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime`. This task should work for your scenario. For more details you can check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880951/10910450).
3. Also you can submit a feature request about `JSON variable substitution` option on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22), which is our main forum for product suggestions. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.